# как записать видео в память устройства?

Tags: android

Как записать видео в внутреннеe хранилище?

```
private static final int VIDEO_CAPTURE = 101;
 Uri videoUri;
 public void startRecordingVideo() {
if   (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FRONT)) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    File mediaFile = new File(
       Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/myvideo.mp4");
    videoUri = Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, videoUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, VIDEO_CAPTURE);
} else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "No camera on device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
}
```

Comment: У вас что-то не работает так как вы хотите. Это всё, что понятно из вопроса. Помимо кода предоставьте описание происходящего, ожидания и результаты

Comment: getExternalStorageDirectory() - пишет на SD карту, а какой метод пишет во внутреннее хранилище? Мне не нужно писать на SD карту видео c Camera а только в память устройства

Comment: getFilesDir() вроде